# Android DialogFragment getDialog() and getView() returning null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I've got a DialogFragment that I need to show from a Fragment. This is my DialogFragment:

```
class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        internal fun newInstance(): MyDialogFragment = MyDialogFragment()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_fragment container, false)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        view.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.cancel_button)?.setOnClickListener { dismiss() }
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
        val dialogView = requireActivity().layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_fragment, null)
        builder.setView(dialogView)

        dialogView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.cancel_button).setOnClickListener { dismiss() }

        return builder.create()
    }

    fun setMyAction(action: () -> Unit) {
        view?.findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.proceed_button)?.setOnClickListener { action() }
    }
}
```

The way I'm calling it from the fragment as this:

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
            myDialogFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), MyDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName());
            myDialogFragment.setMyAction(this::action);
        });
```

The problem I have here is that it is impossible to call `setMyAction` from the calling fragment and call the `action()`, since in the dialog, `view` is `null` just like if I try to get it with `dialog()`. A second problem here is: why is the `onCreateView` never called, just like `onViewCreated`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem I have here is that it is impossible to call setMyAction from the calling fragment and call the action(), since in the dialog, view is null just like if I try to get it with dialog().

The problem that you are experiencing now is that `show()` is asynchronous. The dialog will be created some time later, not by the time `show()` has returned.

The problem that you are not yet experiencing, but will, is that on a configuration change, your activity and its fragment will be recreated by default, and your `OnClickListener` will be lost.

Rather than pushing an event handler in, have the `DialogFragment` expose results (e.g., via a shared `ViewModel`).

> A second problem here is: why is the onCreateView never called, just like onViewCreated?

You overrode `onCreateDialog()`. You cannot both use `onCreateDialog()` and `onCreateView()`/`onViewCreated()`. Pick one and use it.

Comment: Could this be prevented somehow with maybe data binding, for example? I thought I could get away without passing a shared view model for such a small functionality (in the end is just letting the called fragment do some work)

Comment: @noloman: "Could this be prevented somehow with maybe data binding, for example?" -- could *what* be prevented? If you mean make `show()` be synchronous, then no. If you mean prevent Android from having configuration changes, then data binding won't help with that either. You could opt out of every possible configuration change in the manifest, so Android will not destroy/recreate your activity/fragment, but then you will have a lot of additional code for adapting manually to configurations.

Comment: sorry, what I meant was `show()` being synchronous, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I phase semilar problem when i just check dialog is open or not by log and its return null value. So i just add below line and it's work fine.

If you show dialog in fragment then use like

```
DialogFragment dialogFragment = new DialogFragment();  
dialogFragment.show(requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),"Dialog");  
requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

If you show dialog in activity then no need to use requireActivity().